# Creating a Approval Mechanism on PowerApp

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, power-automate

I have a PowerApps based on a SharePoint Online List at the back-end. The App we are using to create and track records. Each record having monthly amount submissions. Each time when a record updates with amount a PowerAutomate Flow triggers to get approval from the respective approver. Presently the approval request is will be sent over the email. But the case is like, there will be hundreds of approval requests to sent over a week and it will be tedious to check each email and approve the request.

Hence i am looking for a solution when the approver will get an email with a link. The link will redirect to another PowerApps Screen, where the person will get a list of all the pending/un-approved items. So that the approver can take actions all at once. There can be a checkbox or a button opposite of every request and by clicking on to the button, the item will be approved.

Can it be possible and if yes, how to achieve this?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the functionality you're looking for is available in the Power Automate website. If you select **Action items > Approvals** in the left-hand navigation, you can see all of your outstanding approval requests. You can use the details pane to see the details of the request and you can approve or reject using the buttons near the top of the page.

[image: Power Automate approvals]

Similar functionality is available in the Flow mobile app. For more details see [Approve requests on your mobile device by using Power Automate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/mobile-approvals).

Comment: Hello @Rob, In my environment we have not provided access to all users to the PowerAutomate. Hence i am afraid whether we can make that or not. But surely i will think of that option. Thanks for the solution. Apart from that any other suggestion/options would be welcomed. Thanks again!

Comment: Hello @Rob, Finally we have implemented the solution suggested by you. We have provided access to all approvers and we will explain them how to browse to Power Automate site and approve each item. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Indeed it helped.